# Bootstrap 4 | Flip card on click()

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

The CSS :active flips my card on mouseDown.  What I need is to replace the mouseDown event with JQuery click() so my card stay flipped, until I click it again.

I tried few options with JQuery, but nothing worked.

Here is the working **CSS**  (on-mousedown)

```
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent; 
  perspective: 1000px;  
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 10px 0 rgba(90,90,90,0.2)
}


.flip-card:active .flip-card-inner {   
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}



.flip-card-back {

  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

And this is the **HTML**

```
<div class="card mb-3  " style="border:0;"  >
<div class="flip-card mb-3 ">

  <div class="flip-card-inner"  >
  <div class="flip-card-front"> 
  <!--Card image-->
  <div class="view overlay">
    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20%287%29.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <!--Card content-->
  <div  class="card-body   " style="border:0; " >       
    <!--Title-->
    <h4 class="card-title">Card title 1</h4>
    <!--Text-->
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
      content.</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnflip1"  >Front</button>
  </div>


  </div>


  <div class="flip-card-back" >
  <!--Card image-->
  <div class="view overlay">
    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20%287%29.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <!--Card content-->
  <div  class="card-body   " style="border:0; " >   
    <!--Title-->
    <h4 class="card-title">Card title 2</h4>
    <!--Text-->
    <p class="card-text">This is the back</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnflip2" >Back</button>  
  </div>

  </div>

  </div>  
  </div>  
</div>
```

I need the card to flip with JQuery on click() event. I cannot use MD, and this lib doesn't work for me: https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just used a class called ".flipped" where you previously had your :active selector.

Then I use jquery to toggle the flipped class when the card is clicked.

```js
$('.flip-card').on('click', 
  function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('flipped')
  }
)
```

```css
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent; 
  perspective: 1000px;  
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 10px 0 rgba(90,90,90,0.2)
}


.flip-card.flipped .flip-card-inner {   
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}



.flip-card-back {

  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card mb-3" style="border:0;"  >
<div class="flip-card mb-3 ">

  <div class="flip-card-inner"  >
  <div class="flip-card-front"> 
  <!--Card image-->
  <div class="view overlay">
    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20%287%29.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <!--Card content-->
  <div  class="card-body" style="border:0;" >       
    <!--Title-->
    <h4 class="card-title">Card title 1</h4>
    <!--Text-->
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
      content.</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnflip1"  >Front</button>
  </div>


  </div>


  <div class="flip-card-back" >
  <!--Card image-->
  <div class="view overlay">
    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20%287%29.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <!--Card content-->
  <div  class="card-body" style="border:0;" >   
    <!--Title-->
    <h4 class="card-title">Card title 2</h4>
    <!--Text-->
    <p class="card-text">This is the back</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnflip2" >Back</button>  
  </div>

  </div>

  </div>  
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Alternatively you can add a 'flip-card' class on your front/back buttons and change the jquery selector to target that class instead of targeting the entire card.